# Pausing a Downloading File in Google Chrome and Hibernate the System, will it resume?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, browser, hibernate

I'm downloading a large **.rar** file in **`GOOGLE CHROME`** but I don't want to leave my system powered on over night. I'm planning to **pause** and **hibernate** the system so that when I switch it back on, I can **resume** the file download in my queue. Is this possible with this method, will it resume the file download where it left off?

Comment: Seems like the easier solution is to just leave the system on.  Don't hibernate the system, let the file download finish, I presume you can provide it AC/DC power.

Comment: reason for down vote ?  so that i aware of what is wrong with my question.

Answer (score 0):

By default Chrome will not resume downloads when your system is suspended / hibernated. You could try the Chrono Download Manager extension which does support pause/resume/resync of downloads.

[Google Chrome - Chrono Download Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn?hl=en)

**EDIT:** There is a new flag you can set in chrome. If you go to the URL below in your address bar:

chrome://flags/#enable-download-resumption

and enable that, it should work to resume a download.